# Android : Making Listview items appear in a particular form

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview items in cardlayout format. These first item of listview is partially visible from bottom of the screen . And rest all items becomes visible as user scrolls it up. 
I want to make make listview items partially overlapping each other, in order to bring a stack effect while cards are in down state.

Comment: show me your layout code here.

Comment: It won't help you since he want just override ListView behavior

Comment: @user81698 : you should use third party library for this custom layout. List view wont help..